# Use of media files with GIT on Bitbucket?

Tags: git, media, bitbucket

I want to use GIT in a game project which will by its very nature have media assets. These are subject to change quite frequently during development. I was considering Bitbucket since their service is top-notch and I have used it for numerous projects in the past.

Whilst they state that they offer unlimited storage I am concerned that the size of the repository will become rather large and possibly 'unfair'.

Q1. Is this likely to be an issue?

Q2. If so, is there a way to prevent GIT from keeping multiple versions of media assets in its archives. I understand that this will prevent version control on media assets, but I see that as a valid compromise.

Answer (score 1):

A `git` repository grows very rapidly if you commit many binary files and change them often.

However, you need a backup for your media files anyway, right? Put the in the same repository. Why use another way when you have a perfect version control solution already?

The only reason not to do so is not about software development at all. It is about price of disk space. If the price for large repository does not bother you - just go for it and you will be happy.

Answer (score 1):

It is also an issue if you have many collaborators and many places where you need to clone that repo: the cost of cloning a large repo will grew, and certain operations will be slower over time.

Storing large files in a separate unique referential is better, and you can still maintain a link with your git commits, with a system like **[git-annex](http://git-annex.branchable.com/)** (since [git doesn't support that kind of mechanism yet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17897705/6309)).

Comment: Unfortunately there is no git-annex support yet on bitbucket.. But there is a ticket:
https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issue/3787/add-git-annex-support-over-ssh-to