# Git in a multi platform solution, with really big files crashes

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, azure-devops

I have a solution with several projects targeting WP8, W8.1(RT), WPF and WCF ;)

The thing is this is a project with tons of data files. Well not so many, but they take 650+MB.
I want them in the repo, and I'm using .visualstudio.com. Using the integrated git control for  2k13, just freezes with an out of memory exception.

I have a knife on my throat as we say here, the project must be done yesterday ;)

Anyways.. any workarounds? I really want them in my solution. But pff could always just use the command line or Git GUI. And mm yes I have 24 gig ram...

Just find it odd that either .visualstudio.com, the git integration or vs2k13 can't handle these sizes..

The main reason why I want this in .visualstudio.com and the integration is that my team members, aren't all up to date with git yet. Particularly not the bash and UI.

Any pointers? :)

Comment: The size and the number of files can be an issue with git: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19494211/6309. Submodule is one solution, but might not be supported yet by the VS git integration.

Comment: What type are those datafiles?

Comment: Maybe you should instruct git to process these files as binary files?

Comment: It should work... Have you tried committing in smaller batches from the commandline if that works, it's a client issue? I've heard of very large commits causing issues even when they shouldn't. I pinged Ed Thompson with this question.

Comment: You could opt for using TFVC which has better large binary file support. If you still want to use Git, use `git tf` to create a local git repo to work against. http://gittf.codeplex.com/

Comment: Might be: https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/pull/2051

Comment: This is might be caused by a bug in LibGit2: https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/pull/2004 which will at some point be integrated into the Visual Studio Tools. Which means that PoShGit or the standard windows commandline should work, since those do not depend on LibGit2, but the Visual Studio add-in will have issues with large files and large commits until this pull request has been integrated into the Visual Studio tools for Git.

Comment: (Which will be the next Update, for what it's worth.)

Comment: Thank you for your replies. Think you have right about the bug there jessehouwing. I was able to include the files into the repo (text based research files, proprietary format).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in LibGit2 which was fixed in the latest Visual Studio 2013 update. To work around it, drop to the commandline and perform the add, commit and push from there. Once the files are added to the repository, you should be able to continue working just fine.

Comment: sorry for the late marking here, I simply missed it or forgot to mark it more likely back then. But here is your answer and upvote. It's so long ago :)