# Does GitLab support large files via git-annex or otherwise?

Tags: git, version-control, gitlab, large-files, git-annex

I run a GitLab instance and would like to allow my users to upload files of almost any size.

It is well-known that git still has problems with large files. I am aware of approaches to circumvent this issue by storing the files somewhere else and versioning just the metadata, e.g. git-annex, git-media and git-fat. Are any of these integrated into GitLab, or would it be easy to do so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of February 18 2015 git-annex is supported on [GitLab 7.8 Enterprise Edition](https://about.gitlab.com/2015/02/17/gitlab-annex-solves-the-problem-of-versioning-large-binaries-with-git/)

Comment: This is excellent news. Any chance this will be available in the community edition eventually?

Comment: The second comment in the above link says "currently have no plans to port this to CE."

Comment: GitLab CEO here, thanks for adding this answer, indeed currently no plans to port this to CE.

Answer (score 2):

This is discussed and open for consideration in [this issue](http://feedback.gitlab.com/forums/176466-general/suggestions/4539840--provide-a-means-for-sharing-large-project-file)

> git-annex can manage links afaik.
>   But it won't allow me to actually store or distribute any files.
>
> GitLab team ADMIN GitLab team (Admin, Gitlab) commented  ·  October 07, 2013 16:51
>   Consider looking into git-annex

But this isn't implemented yet.

Before 5.0, GitLab was using [gitolite](http://gitolite.com/) as an [authorization layer](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/auth.html) (replaced since by [gitlab-shell](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-shell)).
And incidentally, gitolite just integrated git-annex support ([commit b23aed9, March 20th, 2014](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/commit/b23aed9c6d1786bec3617d89db0ad0c9261ff2dc)).

---

Since [GitLab 7.8](https://about.gitlab.com/2015/02/17/gitlab-annex-solves-the-problem-of-versioning-large-binaries-with-git/) (Feb 2015), git-annex is integrated:

> As far as we know GitLab is the first git repository management solution that integrates git-annex.
>   This is possible because both git-annex and GitLab stay very close to the unix paradigms. Internally GitLab uses GitLab Shell to handle ssh access and this was a great integration point for `git-annex`.
>   We've added a setting to GitLab Shell so you can disable GitLab Annex support if you don't want it.