# How to fix "fatal: Cannot handle files this big" in git?

Tags: git, fatal-error

When trying to commit, I get this error:

```
fatal: Cannot handle files this big
```

and nothing else seems to work, I've tried `git reset` and even `git status` fails with the same error.

I don't want to be able to commit large files. Rather, I would like to fix the current state of my working directory and undo adding whichever file caused this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [git with large files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17888604/git-with-large-files)

Comment: Check the linked question - there's a bit of discussion there. Maybe one of the answers there will help you...

Comment: My question is not how to handle large files. Rather, hope to get the repo back in a working state. Right now, I can't do anything, even git status.

Comment: What happens if you move the file out of the git repo using the OS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Deleting the problematic large file from the OS fixed the issue.